# Key error when creating a React Boostrap Navbar dynamically

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a json file that contains my properties for the React-Bootstrap Navbar. I'm getting the error "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop." I have tried to add key={section.id} in the Nav.Link and NavDropdown. In the NavDropdown.Item I used  key={item.id}. The error still occurs and the keys do not appear in the elements. I realize this was not really meant to be built this way, I'm hoping to build the json with some sort of CMS in the future.

```
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import NavDropdown from 'react-bootstrap/NavDropdown';

React Navbar code:
  <Navbar className="nav-color" variant="dark" expand="lg">
    <Navbar.Brand href="#home">My Nav</Navbar.Brand>
    <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
    <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
      <Nav className="mr-auto">
        {props.navData.map(section => {
          return (
            <>
              {section.type === 'link' ? <Nav.Link href={section.path} key={section.id}>{section.category}</Nav.Link> : ''}
              {section.type === 'dropdown' ? <NavDropdown title={section.category} key={section.id} id='basic-nav-dropdown'>
                {section.items.map(item => {
                  return (
                    <>
                      <NavDropdown.Item href={item.path}>{item.title}</NavDropdown.Item>
                    </>
                  )
                })}
              </NavDropdown> : ''}
            </>
          )
        })}
      </Nav>
    </Navbar.Collapse>
  </Navbar>


Example of json:
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "category": "Home",
    "type": "link",
    "path": "/"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "category": "Dropdown1",
    "type": "dropdown",
    "items": [
      {
        "title": "Item1",
        "type": "page",
        "path": "Item1"
      },
      {
        "title": "Item2",
        "type": "page",
        "path": "Item2"
      },
      {
        "title": "Item3",
        "type": "page",
        "path": "Item3"
      },
      {
        "title": "Item4",
        "type": "page",
        "path": "Item4"
      },
      {
        "title": "Item5",
        "type": "page",
        "path": "Item5"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Try adding a key to the `NavDropdown.Item` too, if path is unique to each item, add it as key.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct, sort of, it does not go in the NavDropdown, the <>'s need to change to <div> and have a key. I posted the corrected code in an answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to SakoBu and Akshay for replies. The solution is:

```
 {props.navData.map((section, sIdx) => { //HERE
          return (
            <div key={sIdx}> //HERE
          {section.type === 'link' ? <Nav.Link href={section.path} key={section.id}>{section.category}</Nav.Link> : ''}
          {section.type === 'dropdown' ? <NavDropdown title={section.category} key={section.id} id='basic-nav-dropdown'>
            {section.items.map((item, idx) => { //HERE
                  return (
                    <div key={idx}> //HERE
                  <NavDropdown.Item href={item.path}>{item.title}</NavDropdown.Item>
                </>
              )
            })}
          </NavDropdown> : ''}
        </>
      )
    })}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
  {section.items.map((item, idx) => {
    return (
      <>
        <NavDropdown.Item key={idx} href={item.path}>{item.title}</NavDropdown.Item>
      </>
    );
  })}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Using the key={idx}, I also added myKey={idx} as a test,  this is what appears in the inspection window:

<a href="Item1" class="dropdown-item">Item1</a>

Nothing is passing through. I also did this in the first map in the code and key does not render but myKey does:

<a mykey="0" href="/" data-rb-event-key="/" class="nav-link">Home</a>

Comment: Key is a special prop and would not appear in the dom... if the warning is gone you’re good to go...

Comment: Warning still exists. I'm wondering if I should be too concerned about it.

Comment: What’s the actual warming? It should say file name, line number etc...

Comment: index.js:1 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `Navigation`. See .... react-warning-keys for more information.
    in div (at Navigation.js:30) Line 30 is the <> So I tried to change to a dic and add a key. Still Error

Comment: Then I’m not sure... I’d need to run it locally to debug... ‍♂️

Comment: I appreciate the effort! Thanks

Comment: I lied. It worked. I had a typo in the section.map one. Both maps needed the <div key={sIdx}> for the first one and <div key={idx}> for the second. Thank you very much!